# Retrieving all entries 10 days prior to days in table, which matches where clause

Tags: kdb

I have a random table of data - with dates and numbers:

```
Date                          Open       Volume        abschange
2016.12.08D00:00:00.000000000 11035.76   1.74835e+008  1.30177
2016.12.09D00:00:00.000000000 11170.18   1.0383e+008   0.2994598
2016.12.12D00:00:00.000000000 11198.42   8.98117e+007  0.07331357
...
2016.12.30D00:00:00.000000000 11443.31   4.18109e+007  0.3298871
2017.01.02D00:00:00.000000000 11426.38   4.74561e+007  1.504853
```

So from this table, i would like to be able to create a list, which holds all the entries from 10 days prior to the days, which has abschange>1.

I thought it would be easiest to start with a focus on those dates:

```
 Date                          abschange
 ---------------------------------------
 2016.12.08D00:00:00.000000000 1.30177  
 2017.01.02D00:00:00.000000000 1.504853 
 2017.01.25D00:00:00.000000000 1.099709 
 2017.01.31D00:00:00.000000000 1.344625 
 2017.02.06D00:00:00.000000000 1.016427 
 2017.02.21D00:00:00.000000000 1.265196
```

Then create a flat list:

```
 mynewdates: raze tablewithDateAndabschange each
```

which gives me:

```
2016.12.08D........ 2017.01.02D......
```

Then i get stuck, when i want to add 10 prior dates for each entry in this list.

Could i actually get my wanted result in one line of code, based on the first table or should i follow the path i am on ?

For both - if possible, what would the possible solution to this be ?

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct your requirement is:

- for each date for which abschange>1, get last 10 dates before this date from table.

Below query will create that map. It is based on following assumptions:

- Date column is unique and ordered(ascending) as it appears from your example.

If above condition is not true then it will require a minor change in below query to work with duplicates and unordered list.

- Table is not keyed.

  ```
  q) (tbl[`Date]a)!b@'where@'not null b:tbl[`Date] -1+(a:where 1<tbl`abschange)-\:til 10
  ```

**UPDATE:** Based on discussion in comment section.

Just add the second step to check if dates list for first result is empty. In that case generate last 10 dates from that date.

Finally it generates the table where each row contains prior dates(max 10) for each date with abschange>1.

```
    q)d:b@'where@'not null b:tbl[`Date] -1+(a:where 1<tbl`abschange)-\:til 10
    q)d[0]:$[0=count d 0;(t[`Date]a 0)-1+til 10;d 0]
    q)([]dates:d)
```

Comment: Hi Rahul. Thank you so much for your contrubution! It almost did what i wanted. The data will always be order by date. I have a few issues. The table i get out - I had some difficulties, getting it into a single column table. As well i would like to as well have the dates prior to the first instance, which has abschange>1, even though those days are not initially in the list.

Comment: Hi Niels, for table output just get the value of the dictionary output from my command(i.e. remove the key). Lets store that in some variable for example 'res'. And then to get table just do ([]prior_dates:res). Regarding your second question, if you could clarify it a bit more maybe with an example then I might be able to help you.

Comment: Concerning my second question. In the dataset, the very first date actually fulfills the condition (meaning, i would like to have the 10 dates prior to it), but as it is the first date, there is no prior rows(dates) in the dataset to retrieve.

Comment: Concerning the first question. I assigned the result of your function as this - someresults:(yourfunction). Then i tried to do * 0!someresults * , which then gives me a type error. If i remove the * ! * in the function, the output becomes all 0N 0N 0N 0N 0N.

Comment: For first instance, what is the output you are expecting as there are no dates in table before that. Is it just simply generate last 10 dates from that date? for ex if first instance date is 2018.12.11 then simply generate dates from 2018.12.01 to 2018.12.10?

Comment: Yes, like that would be very great.

Comment: I have updated the answer to match with your requirements.

Comment: Hi Rahul. Just been away for a few days. I get a 'type error on "d" just after count on the second line.

Comment: Could you give me the query to create sample table similar to yours. Because I tried it on example table similar to table in your post and it is working fine.